# How to limit response size for $http service?

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have a Spring controller that returns data in JSON format and AngularJS web app that consumes the data from it. Sometimes the amount of data is so big that it crashes the page without even finishing the request.

That's why I would like to limit the response in size, so I would be able to cancel the request and show the correct error message if necessary. How can I do this?

Comment: Does it crash your page when it receive the response or when you consume it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit the data client-side but if it crashes when you consume the response you could check the `headers` field in JSON response and check the `Content-Lenght` parameter

```
response.headers('content-length');
```

Comment: It won't go to the callback unfortunately. In developer tools I can see that the Content Download goes to some big value and the crash happens.